# Python : Finding the closest RGB values from a list of RGB colors

Tags: python, python-3.9

I am kind of stuck in here, and couldn't find the best performance-effective algorithms to find the 5 closest values to the target value from a list of RGB lists.

The color list:

```
[[212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179]]
```

```
Target color:  [202, 200, 198]
```

```
the expected valaue:
[[#,#,#], [#,#,#], [#,#,#], [#,#,#], [#,#,#]]
```

I am using this set of color lists to find the images with similar colors. There may be duplicated values, and omitting the exact value should be considered as these were extracted from a set of images that can be the exact same photos.

Comment: Have you tried eucledian distance?

Comment: You have to tell us what your "closeness" metric is.  Euclidean?  Manhattan?

Comment: Can you use `numpy`? It would be very convenient.

Comment: Your color list has many repeats and only has 31 unique colors, one of which is the target color. So, the closest 5 would just be the target color.

Comment: @Aplet123 That's why I mentioned "Omitting the exact value". I could easily just omit that on my end, but it'd be useful to build a script considering the duplicated value.

Answer (score 1):

Using euclidean distance:

```py
import math

def distance(a, b):
    return math.hypot(*(v2 - v1 for v1, v2 in zip(a, b)))

colors = [[212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179], [216, 213, 211], [185, 176, 167], [186, 183, 179], [177, 175, 174], [184, 172, 157], [229, 225, 221], [53, 48, 44], [127, 114, 103], [230, 229, 227], [218, 215, 210], [209, 203, 192], [96, 82, 68], [121, 100, 86], [206, 204, 199], [151, 149, 132], [232, 233, 233], [50, 46, 45], [188, 173, 163], [185, 164, 140], [136, 126, 115], [202, 200, 198], [124, 111, 97], [122, 101, 85], [212, 211, 211], [159, 148, 138], [172, 171, 164], [114, 106, 97], [96, 82, 68], [92, 85, 74], [200, 196, 194], [191, 189, 189], [186, 182, 179]]
target = [202, 200, 198]

closest = sorted(colors, key=lambda x: distance(target, x))
print(closest[:5])
```

Answer (score 0):

Without detail definition about what's "closest" RGB, I think this helper may offer you some idea?

import math

```
def distance(c1, c2):
    r1,g1,b1 = c1
    r2,g2,b2 = c2
    return math.sqrt((r1 - r2)**2 + (g1 - g2) ** 2 + (b1 - b2) **2)
```

Then you could pass the color_list to check and match.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. This is just a euclidean distance algorithm that can be found in various places.

Comment: The community spirit isn't sharing ideas for reference. It's providing correct, high-quality answers to specific programming questions. If you don't think the question is clear, or you do not have the actual answer, then you should not post an answer.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for the tips.  Will try the best.